# How to use Grails Domain objects in a Java project?

Tags: grails

I have a Grails application with outsourced (in a separate Grails Plugin) domain objects and would like to use the domain objects in a Java application.

If this is possible, how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to use them as `domain classes`, you need `GORM-plugin` to be installed somehow in your java code. Without the plugin the domain classes lose their "active record" aspect and can be used only as POJOs.

I can barely imagine how to do that w/o lot of pain

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your custom hbm.xml hibernate mapping files. See [hibernate doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-tutorial-basic.html)

Comment: That's what I'd like to ommit.